# Could we have code coloring and monospace font for the code on programming communities?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

[image]

Whats this??? Could we have syntax coloring and monospace font (for example, "Menlo"), at least when you specify language yourself?

Comment: Syntax coloring for what languages? How many are tagged (for example) on SO? How many are used on the code golf SE? Which ought to have syntax coloring?

Comment: @MattGutting At least when you specify language yourself.

Comment: I think this is really a good idea. I think at the very least, for the major languages (C, C++, Java, etc.) and for the languages which show up on code golf a lot (Golf script) but aren't really majorly used. At the very least, I like the mono spaced font idea to differentiate between different parts of a post.

Comment: We should at least have consistency with non-mobile web clients. The screenshot in the question is from StackOverflow, on which that block would be mono-spaced and syntax highlighted in JavaScript. There's no reason to recreate the entire standard for such formatting for the mobile website; it should simply be the same as on non-mobile.